# Documenting Rails API POST action with params in body

Tags: swagger

I am using Ruby on Rails to architect a Rest API for a client and trying to document it by using SwaggerHub.

I would like to know how to document a post action with the correct parameters in the BODY. So far I have the action created and need to describe the following parameters for my developers.

```
{"user": {"email":"999999@gmail.com", "password":"12345678", "password_confirmation":"12345678"}}
```

I have started out with this for my post action:

```
 "post": {
  "description": "Creates a user",
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
    ],
  "responses": {
    "201": {
      "description": "Creates an instance of User",
    },
    "422": {
      "description": "Bad syntax, user not created"
    }
  }
}
```

It's easy to document with the parameters " in PATH like the Get or Delete action which has the user ID in the params like this

```
 "delete": {
  "description": "Destroy a user",
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
    ],
  "responses": {
    "200": {
      "description": "destory a single user",
    },
    "404": {
      "description": "user not found"
    }
  }
},
  "parameters": [
  {
    "name": "id",
    "in": "path",
    "description": "ID of user to use for action",
    "required": true,
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
```

How can I document the parameters with params "in": "body" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a parameters list within the post and add a parameter with in set to body.

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Simple API
  description: A parameter body example  

paths:
  /users:
    post:
      description: creates a user
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: user
          in: body
          schema:
            properties:
              user:
                properties:
                  email:
                    type: string
                  password:
                    type: string
                  password_confirmation:
                    type: string
      responses:
        201:
          description: Creates an instance of User
        422:
          description: Bad syntax, user not created
```

You can find many information about the OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) Specification by reading [the specification description](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) and [this tutorial](http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-1-introduction/) (disclosure: I wrote it).